# Variables Ajax a PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

Tengo un consulta con ajax de la siguiente manera:

**Actualizacion:**

con lo que me han dicho y me quedo con lo siguiente: las variables ajax se manejan con la notación: `{variable1: valor1, variable2: valor2}`
 donde variable1 antes de los puntos son la variable y valor1 después de los puntos es el valor que toma la variable cierto? entonces una vez que modifico mi variable para que tome esa notación y al modificar mi echo de la siguiente manera `echo $_POST['variable']` me arroja el error

**Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebApp\test\consulta2.php on line 80**

adjunto mi codigo como queda ahora:

```
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(clientes){
var dataString = {variable: $('#var').html()}
$.ajax({
    url : 'consulta2.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'html',
    data :  dataString,
})

.done(function(resultado){
    $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
});
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
var valorBusqueda=$('#search').val();
if (valorBusqueda!=""){
    obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
}
else{
    obtener_registros();
}
});
```

Comment: Estas haciendolo mal debe ser  `$variable = $_POST['variable']; echo $variable` o tambien asi `echo $_POST['variable'];`

Comment: el echo lo eh manejado de diferentes formas y en todas me da el mismo error.

Answer (score 1):

Te marca `undefined` porque la variable `variable` en realidad no existe. POST y GET funcionan de diferentes formas, te recomiendo que leas un poco mas al respecto. Pero para lograr lo que necesitas una de las formas de hacerlo es crear un objecto en javascript como

```
let data = {variable: valor, variable2: valor2};
```

y eso mandar en tu petición y en el back ahora sí la variable `variable` estará definida.

Tu código quedaría de la siguente manera:

```
function obtener_registros(clientes){
    var dataString = {variable: $('#var').html()};
    $.ajax({
        url: 'consulta2.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: dataString,
    }).done(function(resultado){
        $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
    });
}
```

Comment: utilizando tu explicacion como referencia ahora me da el siguiente error:  **Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebApp\test\consulta2.php on line 80** la cual es la linea donde tengo el echo.

Comment: @AlexisGarcia es correcto lo que dicen los compañeros: debes pasar a Ajax un objeto construido bajo la notación: `{ clave: valor }` y no una simple concatenación. Y, como ha comentado @Byro en la pregunta, estás herrando en la forma de tratar la variable en PHP. Prueba a hacerlo así: `echo $_POST['variable'];` o bien así: `$variable=$_POST['variable']; echo $variable;`

Comment: acabo de crear una funcion donde al dar click me cambia el texto de un <p> y al dar click me muestra la variable que estoy tratando de importar al php el detalle esta en que la funcion que acabo de realizar me funciona bien en el front si me da el dato de la variable pero en el back sigo teniendo el mismo problema antes solo me decia **undefined** ahora me dice  **Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebApp\test\consulta2.php on line 80**

Comment: Puedes poner el código de tu php para que podamos verlo? 
echo $_POST['variable']; debería funcionar, o puedes hacer un print_r($_POST); y ver qué es lo que está llegando a tu back. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa por que tu estas tratando de enviar un String, cuando en realidad deberías pasar un objeto de JS como el siguiente:

```
var dataString = {variable:valor, variable2:valor2};
```

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi pregunta, eh hecho lo que me dicen pero sigo sin poder importar la variable a mi documento php. en que puede estar el error?